# Simple MPG logic

Tags: java, math, logic

I'm trying to make an MPG calculator, here are test cases and expected results:

My tester:

```
    Car auto = new Car(15);
    System.out.println("New car odometer reading: ");
    auto.fillUp(150,8);
    System.out.println("Miles per gallon" + auto.calculateMPG());
    System.out.println("Miles per gallon" + auto.calculateMPG());
    auto.resetMPG();
    auto.fillUp(350, 10);
    auto.fillUp(450, 20);
    System.out.println("Miles per gallon" + auto.calculateMPG());
    auto.resetMPG();
    auto.fillUp(603, 25.5);
    System.out.println("Miles per gallon" + auto.calculateMPG());
```

Expected Results:

```
New car odometer reading: 15
Miles per gallon: 16.875
Miles per gallon: 16.875
Miles per gallon: 10.0
Miles per gallon: 6.0
```

What I get:

```
New car odometer reading: 
Miles per gallon16.875
Miles per gallon16.875
Miles per gallon15.0
Miles per gallon23.647058823529413
```

I think the problem is with my fillup code but I'm just so stupid rn and cant figure it out...

```
public class Car
{
    private int startMiles;
    private int endMiles;
    private double gallonsUsed;
    private int odometerReading;

    public Car(int odometerReading) {
        startMiles = odometerReading;
        endMiles = odometerReading;
    }

    public void fillUp (int odometerReading, double gallons) {
        endMiles = odometerReading;
        gallonsUsed = gallonsUsed + gallons;
    }

    public double calculateMPG() {
        double MPG = (endMiles-startMiles)/gallonsUsed;
        return MPG;
    }

    public void resetMPG() {
        gallonsUsed = 0;
        startMiles = odometerReading;
        endMiles = odometerReading;
    }
}
```

Please help! I can't figure this out.

Comment: Wild guess: what happens if you change the contents of `resetMPG` to `gallonsUsed = 0; startMiles = endMiles;`?

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that you never advance your `Car` object's `odometerReading` attribute (It is always zero). When you don't initialize a primitive `int`, [it defaults to 0](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

A quick fix is to not set your start and end mileage to your `odometerReading` attribute, but to make your `startMiles` equal to your `endMiles`

With this change, you can also remove the `int odometerReading` attribute, as it won't be used anymore:

```
public class Car
{
    private int startMiles;
    private int endMiles;
    private double gallonsUsed;

    public Car(int odometerReading) {
        startMiles = odometerReading;
        endMiles = odometerReading;
    }

    public void fillUp (int odometerReading, double gallons) {
        endMiles = odometerReading;
        gallonsUsed = gallonsUsed + gallons;
    }

    public double calculateMPG() {
        double MPG = (endMiles-startMiles)/gallonsUsed;
        return MPG;
    }

    public void resetMPG() {
        gallonsUsed = 0;
        startMiles = endMiles;
    }
}
```

New output:

> New car odometer reading:
>   Miles per gallon16.875
>   Miles per gallon16.875
>   Miles per gallon10.0
>   Miles per gallon6.0

---

If you want to match the output to your expected, make these changes to your main class:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Car auto = new Car(15);
        System.out.println("New car odometer reading: " + auto.getEndMiles());
        auto.fillUp(150,8);                            //^^Call a getter method
        System.out.println("Miles per gallon: " + auto.calculateMPG());
        System.out.println("Miles per gallon: " + auto.calculateMPG());
        auto.resetMPG();                  //^ just add a colon and space                  
        auto.fillUp(350, 10);
        auto.fillUp(450, 20);
        System.out.println("Miles per gallon: " + auto.calculateMPG());
        auto.resetMPG();
        auto.fillUp(603, 25.5);
        System.out.println("Miles per gallon: " + auto.calculateMPG());
    }
```

To support this, you'll have to add a Getter method to your `Car` class, so you can print your current mileage:

```
public int getEndMiles() {
    return endMiles;
}
```

New output:

> New car odometer reading: 15
>   Miles per gallon: 16.875
>   Miles per gallon: 16.875
>   Miles per gallon: 10.0
>   Miles per gallon: 6.0

Comment: Will try and get back to you within 87.3 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Your `odometerReading` field is always 0. `resetMPG()` resets also `startMiles` and `endMiles` to that value.

I guess the `odometerReading` field should always show the overall mileage show it should be set in fillup. Using the same name for the method parameter adds to the confusion.